# How can I make a block comment in React (JavaScript) use single line comment notation of // not /* <App><Home /></App>} */ in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, comments

How can I make a block comment in React (JavaScript) use single line comment notation of // not /* } */ in VS Code

Please see block comment of /* ... */ vs // ...

````
Example of what I do not want:
{/* <App> 
  <Home />
</App> */}

Example of what I do want:
// <App>  
  // <Home />
// </App>

Example 2 of alternative of what I do want, a per line commenting not block commenting:
{/* <App>   */}
  {/* <Home />   */}
{/* </App>   */}```
````

Comment: You can't. You can't just change the syntax of the language

Comment: Commenting the lines individually gives me what I want, trying to find out if there is a way to select multiple lines and have them be commented individually. I want to comment out say 10 lines of code and be able to stop commenting out say the last 2 lines of code in a more quick way. Yes @cbr

Comment: Do I understand correctly that what you're really asking is that when using "toggle line comment" or "toggle block comment" in VS Code, you want to know if you can make it actually use per-line comments, instead of commenting out the entire selected block?

Comment: In vs code `ctrl` + `/` (`cmd` + `/` on mac) to toggle comment

Comment: @KonradLinkowski It appears that when using "toggle line comment" in JSX in VS Code, the editor actually places a block comment instead of commenting out each line individually with `{/* */}`.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does not work for you when selescting multiple lines - I think it should put a line comment on each line, then consider the extension below.

Take a look at this extension (that I wrote): [Toggle Line Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.toggle-comments).  It does what you want.  Some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+/",         // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "toggle-comments.toggleLineComments",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascriptreact"
}
```

If you want to restrict it to `javascriptreact` files, use the full when clause above.  In which case you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> as the keybinding if you wanted to.